# Mixing and extending Spring XML configuration

Tags: spring, jaxb

I have a Spring MVC project using XML for the main config, including registering JAXB classes.  I'm now making this into a multi-module app, and have a separate project that creates an optional JAR file.  The JAR file adds things like @Controller and @Service classes to the main MVC project, but the main project does not depend on that JAR, and I want to keep it that way, so I don't want to have to customise the application context xml in the main project in order to add in support for the optional JAR; I just want to add that JAR to the classpath.

In that optional JAR, I'm successfully using a class with a @Configuration annotation to create new beans in my application context, but I now need to extend an existing bean, to add in new JAXB annotated classes and packages containing ObjectFactory classes, etc.

I can't see how to do this...

I've tried to wildcard the marshaller packages like this:

```
<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
   <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app.xml.**"/>
</bean>
```

but that doesn't seem to be working, since I get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to locate object to be marshalled in model
```

Is there another approach I can take?  Ideally, I'd like to have a method in my @Configuration class that just adds in new classes to an existing Jaxb2Marshaller bean...

Or even better, find a way to get Spring to detect all classes with JAXB annotations on startup...

I'm using Spring 3.2.1 and JAXB2 via Spring OXM

Comment: Rather than using wildcards use multiple package name separated by comma.Because it does not identify the wildcards and the property "packagesToScan" accepts String array.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to avoid, because it means I create a dependency on those packages from my main applicationContext.xml.  I'm investigating other ways

Answer (score 0):

I don't think spring supports this use case, but what you can do is extend `Jaxb2Marshaller`, and using a utility like [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to find all the classes that have jaxb annotations and add them to the marshaller.

Also, if you're using spring and don't mind using some features it provides, you can use the class [`ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) to find for classes. This is what spring uses internally to scan packages and subpackages.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use  `<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app.xml.**"/>` as packagesToScan property is not available for jaxb2Marshaller..
instead of that you can use

```
<property name="contextPath" value="{package name where all classes are generated}"/>
```

The following works

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" >
<property name="contextPath" value="{package name where all classes are generated}"/>
</bean>
```